# Mysql split the column values based on the joining table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I need a query to find the count based on the multiple table. Please Check the below details

I am having 3 tables as table_1, table_2, table_3 and table_1 is the primary table, and other 2 are inherited from the primary. these table has the common value of profile_id column. Check this sample query counter

```
SELECT COUNT(profile_id) 
from table_1 
WHERE profile_id IN (SELECT profile_id FROM table_2)
```

the above query returns the count based on the `table_2 profile id`. But i need query with all the tables separately like as below

```
SELECT COUNT(profile_id) as table_2count, 
       COUNT(profile_id) as table_3count 
FROM table_1 WHERE (the two condition)
```

In above query table_2count is based on the table_2 profiles and table_3count will be based on the table_3. How can i merge these values into single query. Please suggest some methods to find out the count values.

Comment: why is sql-server and php tagged here?

Comment: is `profile_id` the unique in `table_1`?

Comment: @ughai. Yes profile_id is unique..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `profile_id` is unique in `table_1` and you have foreign keys in `table_2` and `table_3`, you don't really need to join back with table_1, what you need is something like this.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct profile_id) FROM table_2) table_2count,
(SELECT COUNT(distinct profile_id) FROM table_3) table_3count
```

If you really need a join or there are no FKs defined, you can use this

```
SELECT
    COUNT(distinct t2.profile_id) table_2count,
    COUNT(distinct t3.profile_id) table_3count
FROM table_1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 on t1.profile_id = t2.profile_id
    LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 on t1.profile_id = t3.profile_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 subqueries to achieve that:

```
 SELECT
      t1.*,   -- get all data from t1 + two counts from t2 and t3
      (SELECT COUNT(t2.profile_id) 
       FROM table_2 t2 
       WHERE t2.profile_id = t1.profile_id) as count2,
      (SELECT COUNT(t3.profile_id) 
       FROM table_3 t3 
       WHERE t3.profile_id = t1.profile_id) as count3
    FROM table_1 t1
    WHERE <your conditions for table_1 go here>
```